# Build netbeans project from command line is a little different

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I would like to build my project from the command line and make a hash of the output.

I used this script which seemed to work:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
set PATH=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.9.1\java\ant\bin;%PATH%
ant clean jar
```

It builds my project without errors, but the output is not binary equal. How can I call ant in exactly the same way as netbeans?

edit: I need the output to be equal because I want to compare md5 hash and compare to my version control. I'm using kdiff3 to compare and I have also extracted the jars and the different files seems to be related to a webservice client in my program.

Comment: How do you know "the output is not binary eqaul"? What method do you use for this comparison?

Comment: Why do u care about the output... when both work perfectly?

Comment: Are you using exactly the same JVM and dependency jars in Netbeans as are accessed from the command line? Maybe the manifests are different - use something like BeyondCompare to check differences between the two artefacts.

Comment: Dave, how can the manifest be different? I am using the ant supplied with netbeans and the same jvm. I have noticed that netbeans ant runs in-process. There is no ant app in the process list.

Comment: I've found this question which deals with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275599/how-can-ant-compile-and-jar-byte-identical-jar-files-i-e-so-md5-matches-unless It turns out the md5 are different even between different compiles from netbeans. I feel a little stupid I didn't figure that out the first time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the `ant` version stored in the manifest. NetBeans installs its own Ant, it can be different than the one installed in your system (acessible on your PATH). You should do the checksum only for the classes.

The jar created by NetBeans is like This

```
MyProgram.jar
 |
 |-> META-INF
 |     |
 |     |-> MANIFEST.MF
 |
 |-> package1
 |    |
 |    |-> classes of package1 and other packages
 |
 |-> package2
 |  ...
 |
 |-> package3
    ...
```

You should unzip your jar file and create the checksum based on the files under the folder that are your programs packages, i.e. `package1`, `package2`, `package3` etc. `MANIFEST.MF` holds the version of `ant` and `jdk` used to create the application.

Comment: It just contains:Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: Isn't it the `manifest.mf` in the root directory of your NetBeans project? If it is, take a look on the `MANIFEST.MF` **inside** the jar file NetBeans built.