# Post-process jar after assembly but before installation (to get idempotent builds)

Tags: java, maven, build-process

We use Jenkins which use md5 fingerprinting to identify artifacts and whether the artifact has changed since the last build.  Unfortunately Maven builds always generate binary different artifacts.

Therefore I am looking into making Maven generate the same jar artifact for the same set of input files regardless of where and when they were built, which amongst other things mean that the entries in the jar file must be sorted - not only in the index, but in the order they are written to the jar file.

After examining maven-jar-plugin which use maven-assembly-plugin, my conclusions are that they do not collect all files to be written in memory before writing them all at once, but write one at a time.   This mean that it may be better to postprocess the generated jar instead of changing the current behavior so I at that time can sort the entries, zero the timestamps, etc.

I am unfamiliar with writing Maven plugins, so my question is, how should I write a plugin which Maven knows how to tell where the artifact-jar-in-progress is located and how I hook it up in my pom.xml?

(At first I need this to work for jar files, but war files would be nice too).

Comment: Same idea for ant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7275599/53897

Comment: (just saw that shade:shade also manipulates an artifact - might be relevant)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, this can be done based on something similar to `maven-shade-plugin`. I went ahead and wrote a simple plugin to add this capability -- see https://github.com/manouti/jar-timestamp-normalize-maven-plugin (available on the [Central repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/manouti/jar-timestamp-normalize-maven-plugin/)).

The behavior is based on the `shade` plugin. It consists of a single goal called `normalize` which can be bound to the `package` lifecycle phase and configured in the project's POM:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.manouti</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar-timestamp-normalize-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jar-normalize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>normalize</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

A few notes about the plugin:

1. The artifact under build is accessed via `project#getArtifact()` where `project` is a `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject`.
2. Normalization consists of mainly three steps:

   - Setting the last modified time of all Jar entries to a specific timestamp (default value is `1970-01-01 00:00:00AM` but can be changed via `-Dtimestamp` system property).
   - Reordering (alphabetically) of attributes in the manifest except for `Manifest-Version` which always comes first.
   - Removing comments from the `pom.properties` file which contain a timestamp that causes the Jar to differ from one build to another.

Once invoked, the goal will generate the output file next to the original artifact (named `artifactId-version-normalized.jar`), i.e. in the `project.build.directory` directory.

Comment: This looks good.  I believe you need an extra step, namely reordering the entries in the jar file too, as the assembly plugin adds file in the order found in the filesystem which typically is unordered.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I patched to do that. Feel free to edit to your needs.

Comment: The simple sort you do, does not keep the manifest as the first in the jar file (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).

Comment: It is not clear how the entries are sorted. On my filesystem, it seems they are ordered according to the filesystem preference (alphabetically), but in all cases looping over the entries programmatically (using `JarFile`) always gets the manifest first.

Answer (score 0):

To create maven plugin project

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DgroupId=sample.plugin \
  -DartifactId=hello-maven-plugin \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin
```

invoke this command it will generate a skeleton project with a class called `MyMojo.java`

write your stuff inside `execute()` method, and install that plugin to your repository by `mvn clean install`

then attach its execution with your project, in your project `pom.xml`

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>sayhi</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

to access project properties inside your Mojo

```
    /**
     * The Maven project.
     *
     * @parameter expression="${project}"
     * @required
     * @readonly
     */
    private MavenProject        project;
```

and then

```
project.getProperties("build.directory")
```

and [read other properties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) to determine your jar file packed

---

**See**

- [maven: guide-java-plugin-development](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)

Comment: And how is this plugin told about the jar-in-progress so I can manipulate it?

Comment: This answer only addresses the easy part of the question (how to write a Maven plugin), not the interesting part, (how to write a plugin that does X).

Comment: You can tweak your plugin to replace the file right before it installs

Comment: The op did not ask for a solution but about Maven plugins. I suggest you should use annotations not doclets eg.: `@Required`, `@Readonly` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on creating a custom maven plugin seems like a better option. I dont know about an existing plugin provides solution for what you asked.

md5 checksum (or sha-1 in my repository) is generated with install plugin, so seems like you need to extend this or write a new plugin which works after install phase.

I have 2 suggestions about this plugin:

**1)** When thinking simple, this plugin should:

- Read generated jar:

  - Extract all entries.
  - Exclude some entries (e.g. MANIFEST.MF).
  - Sort remaining entries .
  - Extract md5s for each in memory.
  - Generate a single md5 from all of those extracted.

However when considering about where & when independency: Accordig to .class file structure [Java_class_file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) there is minor, major versions entries are held in compiled class files. So if compiler changes, .class files will be changed. In this case we need a check on source code level from this point :( So this solution become useless if there is no guarantee on copiler version.

---

**2)** As very dirty but easy solution, this plugin may only extract your module's `pom.xml` file's *md5* code. But you must guarantee each change in your jar reflects to a minor version (or built number) manually.

Comment: Any modern maven project needs to explicitly specify the source and target level of the Java version used.  Also the Eclipse Compiler for Java (ecj) allows for using a JRE instead of a JDK making the compiler independent of the Java version used.

Comment: My concern was regarding to minor version of compiled class. I agree, we can compile code regarding to a specified major version. Need to test what if 2 different compilers with different minor versions create identical .class files

Comment: When using the eclipse compiler specified in the maven project the output should be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own plugin you can write a Groovy script that is executed by [groovy-maven-plugin](http://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute.html):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>
              import java.util.jar.*
              String fileName = '${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar'
              println "Editing file ${fileName}"
              JarFile file = new JarFile(fileName);
               // do your edit
          </source>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```